# ClassName::CLASS in PHP 5.4 with Symfony Framework

Tags: php, symfony

I just moved a working Symfony installation from one folder to another. Now I get the error

```
FatalErrorException: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'CLASS' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ...
```

I know the Classname::CLASS method is implemented in PHP 5.5. But I use PHP 5.4 and until today everything worked fine. The CLASS Method is used in several Classes in vendor directory eg in the Gos\Bundle\WebSocketBundle which is required. I don't know what I made to crash this running system by moving it to another directory.

Comment: This is a pretty confusingly worded question. Can you link the PHP documentation where you think static references are new in PHP 5.5? As far as I know, it's been available *at least* since 5.3 - if not earlier. Your use of the word "method" is confusing here too. Do you mean the programming term method (a function that is defined in a *Class*)? Or the non-programming specific term (a procedure for doing something)?

Comment: @HPierce PHP 5.5 added a special “class constant” that you can access like `\MyNamespace\MyClass::class` and it would then return `"MyNamespace\MyClass"`. [PHP doc entry](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class.class)

Comment: So what exactly is the question here? Yes, the `::class` feature doesn’t exist in PHP 5.4, so if one of your dependencies use it that won’t work. Perhaps you are using a newer version of one of your bundles in the new directory that uses this feature?

Comment: Finally I found solution that the bundles using ::class worked only in cache. After clearing the cache and using PHP 5.4 instead of 5.6 it crashed

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful as long as you're stuck with PHP 5.4.
But be aware that support for PHP 5.4 already ended - so you should not be relying anymore!

We did it the following with a trait as a temporary solution until we upgraded to PHP 5.5:

```
/**
 * Trait to supplement the PHP 5.5 function ::class
 *
 */
trait ClassName
{
 /**
 * Returns the Full name of a class (equivalent of ::class which can be used starting from php 5.5)
 *
 * @return string the class name including namespace
 */
static public function CLASSNAME()
{
    return get_called_class();
}
}
```

and use it in some base class:

```
use ClassName;

class MyClass {
 use ClassName;

....
 }
```